# What are the names of the different levels of English?

Tags: style, technical-writing, resources

In a recent discussion regarding software manuals, we came across the issue of different styles of writing / speaking in English. I am having a hard time finding a list of the different styles, such as vernacular, slang, old-fashioned, the type of talk one would use with a professor, and such.

What is the name of the preferred writing style for software manuals, and where might one find a list of the different styles?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is ambiguous, off-topic or both. Do you ask if slang is the preferred writing style for manuals?

Comment: No, I ask what are the names of the different writing styles, and what is the name of the preferred writing style for software manuals?

Comment: Casual, formal, technical?

Comment: @cornbreadninja - I *think* that's what's meant here. Maybe? dotancohen, would you like to take this to chat? Maybe we can make this more specific.

Comment: Thanks, cornbread. Those are quite the styles that I am looking for. Too bad that Google Sets is gone, I cannot find a list with those items. I would love to take this to chat, but I am at work and cannot be available immediately as a chat would require.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the name of the preferred writing style for software manuals,
>   and where might one find a list of the different styles?

Software manual authorship falls under [technical writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_writing).  Business correspondence is an example of *formal writing*, and a letter to your grandma is an example of *casual writing*.

Comment: You're welcome!  I'm sorry it isn't more comprehensive or cited.  I will improve the answer as best I can.

Comment: Actually, you address exactly the three types of writing that I needed to know the names of.